# What is url of cloud tally running or not check

Tags: tally

For local we check http://localhost:9000
For cloud tally what is url

For cloud tally how we can check ,
Extally i need to give xml request to cloud tally

Comment: you can use through public Ip
Ex: publicIp:port

Comment: Anyone who knowns the public IP,
Can access all your tally data